# Default TaskCreationOptions in Task.Run

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, threadpool, async-await, c#-5.0

Why the default value for `CreationOptions` of a `Task` created using `Task.Run` is `DenyChildAttach` rather than `None`?

Has it anything to do with making work with the new `async` and `await` in C# 5.0 simpler (by preventing you from escaping current scheduler of current context I guess)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stephen Toub explains this well [in his blog post on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/09/22/new-taskcreationoptions-and-taskcontinuationoptions-in-net-4-5.aspx).

[Parent and child tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417.aspx) are somewhat common when using `Task`s in a parallel fashion. Note that when a parent `Task` has a child, the parent's completion semantics change subtly.

Parent/child tasks are almost never used when using `Task`s in an `async` fashion. In the `async` world, you have a sort of "logical parent/child relationship" when one `async` method calls another, but it is not actually implemented using parent/child tasks.

Usually a `Task` intended for use in `async` code is not expecting to have its completion semantics changed by a child task attaching to it. Thus, the new default for `Task.Run` is `DenyChildAttach`, which prevents any child tasks attempting to attach.

Answer (score 8):

> Why the default value for CreationOptions of a Task created using
>   Task.Run is DenyChildAttach rather than None?

There is no (default or other) options in creating a task using [Task.Run Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run.aspx).

Citing from [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew (by Stephen Toub - MSFT)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx):

- Task.Run "should simply be thought of as a quick way to use Task.Factory.StartNew without needing to specify a bunch of parameters.  It’s a shortcut"
- `Task.Run(someAction);` is exactly equivalent to:

  ```
  Task.Factory.StartNew
      (   someAction
          , CancellationToken.None
          , TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach
          , TaskScheduler.Default
       );
  ```
- "In this way, Task.Run can and should be used for the most common cases"

MSDN article [Nested Tasks and Child Tasks (for .NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), i.e. without any equivokes for C# 5.0/.NET 4.5) states:

> "in most scenarios, we recommend that you use nested tasks because the
>   relationships with other tasks are less complex. That is why tasks
>   created inside other tasks are nested by default, and you must
>   explicitly specify the AttachedToParent option to create a child task"

which explains why `CreationOptions.DenyChildAttach` was chosen for the shortcut's most common and simplest option.