# ContinueWith loses the SynchronizationContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await, c#-5.0

In the snippet below, the `SynchronizationContext` is lost, and because of that also the `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture`. `Log()` comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20087132/247702).

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    Log("before GetAsync");
    await new HttpClient().GetAsync("http://www.example.com/")
        .ContinueWith(request =>
        {
            Log("ContinueWith");
            request.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);

    return View();
}

static void Log(string message)
{
    var ctx = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("{0}; thread: {1}, context: {2}, culture: {3}, uiculture: {4}",
        message,
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
        ctx != null ? ctx.GetType().Name : String.Empty,
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name,
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name);
}
```

This is the output:

> before GetAsync; thread: 56, context: AspNetSynchronizationContext, culture: nl, uiculture: nl
>   ContinueWith; thread: 46, context: , culture: nl-BE, uiculture: en-US

Before the `GetAsync`, the culture and UI culture have the values I set in `Application_BeginRequest`. Inside the `ContinueWith`, the context is missing, the culture is set to what's provided by the browser, and UI culture is set to some default.

From what I understand, everything with `AspNetSynchronizationContext` should be happening automatically. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you sure you need `ContinueWith` and `TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent` here? Check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/09/22/new-taskcreationoptions-and-taskcontinuationoptions-in-net-4-5.aspx) to make sure `TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent` gives you the expected behavior.

Comment: @Noseratio I believe so, yes. See [Why does this async code sometimes fail, and only when not observed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175885/why-does-this-async-code-sometimes-fail-and-only-when-not-observed). Feel free to post a better solution if mine is not correct.

Comment: @Noseratio Is it better to avoid `ContinueWith` altogether? It starts to feel like I'm digging myself into a hole for no reason. In short, I'm doing a Web API request, deserialise the response and execute a callback.

Comment: Yes, I think you really don't need `ContinueWith` here. Why can you not just use `async/await`?

Comment: @Noseratio This project was our first time making use of `async`, I guess during our attempts we found that `ContinueWith` (seemingly) worked and we ended up keeping that code. I'll try rewriting the calls, thank you for your input.

Comment: No problem, I also tried to address the second comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23216300/1768303).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to force scheduling of the continuation on the request context thread, you need to specify the `TaskScheduler` that should be used when scheduling the continuation.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    Log("before GetAsync");
    await new HttpClient().GetAsync("http://www.example.com/")
        .ContinueWith(request =>
        {
            Log("ContinueWith");
            request.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }, 
        TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent,
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    return View();
}
```

Howver, you are using `await` which automatically marshals continuations on to the current `SynchronizationContext`. You should be able to do this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        Log("before GetAsync");
        HttpResponseMessage request = await new HttpClient().GetAsync("http://www.example.com/");

        //everything below here is you 'continuation' on the request context
        Log("ContinueWith");
        request.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: The overload of the first snippet isn't correct, but `CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` compiles and the context is passed. Is `CancellationToken.None` correct? The second snippet isn't quite correct, either.

Comment: @Stijn well spotted. That overload always catches me out. was it just the semi-colon in the second snippet?

Comment: In the second snippet, `request` isn't defined and I'm not sure what you meant to type in the snippet.

Comment: @Gusdor: Each method captures its own context, so it doesn't matter if `GetAsync` uses `ConfigureAwait(false)`; `await` will Do The Right Thing even if it does. There's no need to use `ConfigureAwait(true)`.

Comment: @StephenCleary i must be mixed up. Funnily enough, I sourced my understanding of configure await from your blog! http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Comment: @Gusdor: Sorry about that. I attempted to explain it in the `each "level" of async method calls has its own context` part of that post. It is a bit hard to explain, though.

Comment: @StephenCleary not a problem. A re-read has made it very clear.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try with `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`? It should ran the continuation task in the same thread...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions

*"Specifies that the continuation task should be executed synchronously. With this option specified, the continuation will be run on the same thread that causes the antecedent task to transition into its final state. If the antecedent is already complete when the continuation is created, the continuation will run on the thread creating the continuation. Only very short-running continuations should be executed synchronously."*

Comment: That didn't help, I've tried both `TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent | TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` and `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`.